# specifying argument default value in function definition causes error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '='

Tags: c++, c, dll, extern-c

I have following declaration:

```
DLL EntityHandle scenemanager_create_entity
    (SceneManagerHandle handle,
    const char* name,
    const char* mesh_name,
    const char* group_name = 0);
```

where last agrument has default value `group_name = 0`.

When I compile C++ DLL (/TP) it works fine and while compiling a macro DLL is following:

```
#define DLL extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
```

But when I try to compile C application (/TC) linked with this DLL it gives error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '=' and macro DLL is following:

```
#define DLL __declspec(dllimport)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no default arguments in C.

You could use macro `__cplusplus` that to check whether the code is compiled by the C++ compiler or C compiler.

For example

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
// C++ function declaration...
#else
// C function declaration...
#endif
```